# ember.js textfield and css (twitter bootstrap)

Tags: css, ember.js

I want to put some styling on an `Ember.Textfield`, namely: `style="max-width: 100%;"`.
I've tried to do this with `attributeBinding` but without much success. Does anybody have working solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

although you should better use CSS classNames, you can extend the Ember.TextField and add 'style' to the attributebindings

```
App.StyledTextField : Ember.TextField.extend({
  attributeBindings: ['style', 'type', 'value', 'size']
})
```

now you can do something like this:

```
{{view App.StyledTextField 
  style="max-width: 100%"}}
```

Comment: Nice! Tried that yesterday but put the style: 'max-width: 100%' directly in the StyledTextField under the attributeBinding. I might however have had attributeBinding without the **s**